# Python - how to convert int to string represent a 32bit Hex number

Tags: python, integer, hex

I want to get a python solution for this problem:

e.g.

```
integer 1 -> string "0x00000001"
integer 64 -> string "0x00000040"
integer 3652458 -> string "0x0037BB6A"
```

The string size will not be change if number is in `range(0, 2**32)`.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
'0x%08X' % 3652458
```

or (with Python 2.6 and newer)

```
'0x{0:08X}'.format(3652458)
```

both return:

```
'0x0037BB6A'
```

Comment: I'd like to give you another +1 for including `format` in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.6 you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
formatted = f"0x{3652458:08X}"
```

f-strings allow you to put values in a string, where they are actually supposed to go, instead of having to juggle a number of format parameters in your head:

```
value = 3652458
print(f"Your formatted value is 0x{value:08x}")
```